# PDFBox 2.0.25 java.io.IOException: Unknown dir object c='>' cInt=62 peek='>' peekInt=62 at offset 26096 (start offset: 26096)

Tags: java, pdfbox

i'am using PDFBox version 2.0.25 got error

> java.io.IOException: Unknown dir object c='>' cInt=62 peek='>' peekInt=62 at offset 26096 (start offset: 26096)

line the code of error is

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(inputFile);
```

tryng on open document, some reference try with

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(inputFile);
```

but PDFBox version 2.0.25 there is no such function 'loadNonSeq'

full log error

```
java.io.IOException: Unknown dir object c='>' cInt=62 peek='>' peekInt=62 at offset 26096 (start offset: 26096)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseDirObject(BaseParser.java:913)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSDictionaryValue(BaseParser.java:154)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSDictionaryNameValuePair(BaseParser.java:288)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSDictionary(BaseParser.java:218)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseDirObject(BaseParser.java:857)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseFileObject(COSParser.java:907)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseObjectDynamically(COSParser.java:876)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseObjectDynamically(COSParser.java:796)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseDictObjects(COSParser.java:756)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.initialParse(PDFParser.java:187)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:226)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1105)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1088)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1047)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:995)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

any suggestion ? Thank you

Comment: The PDF file might be invalid. Have you tried to validate it, e.g. on https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx ?

Comment: after check Compliance pdf1.6
Result Document validated successfully. the file create with fpdf but containing image

Comment: There is only PDDocument.load() in 2.0.25 . The file is likely broken, please share it.

Comment: Considering the stack trace, maybe a dictionary key without a value? Or a follow-up error of a non-name key in a dictionary? Anyways, without the PDF in question this is pure guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

CMS Signature should be Hex value so i have commented. Pls find below. Even i have got same problem solved by commenting below line

```
byte[] cmsSignature = Base64.decodeBase64(signedHash);
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(inputFile, "rw");
raf.seek(offset);
raf.write(Hex.getBytes(cmsSignature));
// raf.write(cmsSignature);
raf.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using version 3.0.1 helped me to get rid of that exception (that I had with some documents even in latest version 2.0.30).

When updating then have a look at the migration guide ( https://pdfbox.apache.org/3.0/migration.html ) because e.g. you have to use `Loader.loadPDF` instead of `PDDocument.load`.